# libcurl inbuilt compression support or not

Tags: c++, compression, libcurl

I found an answer which told me that libcurl doesn't support compression.

[libcurl (linux, C) - Is there a built-in way to POST/PUT a gzipped request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732950/libcurl-linux-c-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-post-put-a-gzipped-request)

But, somewhere else, I also found this:

[Is there any compression available in libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379888/is-there-any-compression-available-in-libcurl)

My question is, do I still have to compress strings on my own and then send them, or is that not necessary using libcurl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you *send* data you must compress that yourself before sending. There is no support for doing that "automatically" in for example HTTP (neither 1.1 nor HTTP/2).